# EF Core: dbcontext issues in blazor server app

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-server-side

I'm developing an app in Blazor server and I'm getting different errors when I try to perform some operations.

I have my solution structured in 3 projects

- A backend Project with Repository - Service architecture and MySql DB
- A Models in a class library to store my models
- A Blazor Server frontend.
- A xUnit test Project

I get the following error

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: The instance of entity type 'Provincia' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdProvincia'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values

This error appears when I try to persist `Localidad` entity in my `Crear.razor`, my dbcontext here has a lifetime service equal to `Transient`.

Other issue, is when I change the lifetime of the service for the DbContext, if I set it to `Scoped` (*or remove it, which is the default*) the CRUD operations are working, but If I do a refresh in the page (press <kbd>F5</kbd>) the following error shows up

> **InvalidOperationException**: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913

Here's my code (*the imports are omitted*)

**Localidad.cs**

```
namespace CapacitacionModelos.Modelos
{
    [Table("Localidad")]
    public class Localidad
    {
        [Column("IdLocalidad")]
        public int LocalidadId { get; set; }
        [Column("Descripcion")]
        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IdProvincia")]
        public int IdProvincia { get; set; }
        public virtual Provincia Provincia { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Abreviatura { get; set; }
        [Column("IdMPF")]
        public byte? IdMpf { get; set; }

        public Localidad()
        {
         
        }
        public Localidad(string Nombre, Provincia Provincia)
        {
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
            this.Provincia = Provincia;
        }
    }
}
```

**Provincia.cs**

```
namespace CapacitacionModelos.Modelos
{
    [Table("Provincia")]
    public class Provincia
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdProvincia { get; set; }
        [Column("Descripcion")]
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public Provincia()
        {
        }
        public Provincia(string Nombre)
        {
            this.Nombre = Nombre;
        }
    }
}
```

**LocalidadService.cs**

```
namespace CapacitacionesBE.Data
{
    public interface ILocalidadService : IRepository<Localidad>
    {
        public Task<List<Localidad>> GetLocalidadesByProvincia(int idProvincia);
        public Task<List<Localidad>> GetLocalidadesWithProvincias();
    }
    public class LocalidadService : Service<Localidad>, ILocalidadService
    {
        public LocalidadService(LengaContext context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        public async Task<List<Localidad>> GetLocalidadesByProvincia(int idProvincia)
        {
            return await _context
                .Localidades
                .Where(localidad => localidad.Provincia.IdProvincia == idProvincia)
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<Localidad>> GetLocalidadesWithProvincias()
        {
            return await _context
                .Localidades
                .Include(localidad => localidad.Provincia)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**IRepository.cs**

```
namespace CapacitacionesBE.Data
{
    public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
    {
        public Task<List<T>> GetAll();
        public Task<T> GetById(int Id);
        public Task<T> Insert(T Element);
        public Task<T> Update(T Element);
        public Task Delete(int Id);

    }
}
```

**Service.cs**

```
namespace CapacitacionesBE.Data
{
    public class Service<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly LengaContext _context;

        public Service(LengaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task Delete(int Id)
        {
            var ItemToDelete = _context.Set<T>().Find(Id);
            if (ItemToDelete != null)
            {
                _context.Set<T>().Remove(ItemToDelete);
                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                var Items =  await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
                return Items;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error no se pueden traer las entidades: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public async Task<T> GetById(int Id)
        {
            var Item = await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(Id);

            return Item;
        }

        public async Task<T> Insert(T Element)
        {
            if (Element != null)
            {
                _context.Set<T>().Add(Element);
                
                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                return Element;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task<T> Update(T Element)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Update(Element);

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return Element;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**
*I only copied the configureServices method, there's no need for the rest of the file*

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){

                services.AddRazorPages();
                services.AddServerSideBlazor();
                services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
    
                services.AddDbContext<LengaContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(
                   Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

                services.AddScoped<IProvinciaService, ProvinciaService>();
                services.AddScoped<ILocalidadService, LocalidadService>();
                services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, IsOperadorHandler>();
                services.AddScoped<IStringLocalizer<App>, StringLocalizer<App>>();
   }
```

**Crear.razor** *this is my view*

```
@page "/Localidades/Crear"
@using CapacitacionModelos.Modelos
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
@using LengaFE.Shared.Components;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@inject CapacitacionesBE.Data.ILocalidadService _serviceLocalidad
@inject CapacitacionesBE.Data.IProvinciaService _serviceProvincia
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject ILogger<Crear> Logger

@inject IStringLocalizer<App> L;

<h3>Crear</h3>

<EditForm Model="@Localidad" OnValidSubmit="@HandleSubmit">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Localidad" class="control-label">@L["localidad"]</label>
                <input form="Nombre" class="form-control" @bind="@Localidad.Nombre" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Provincia" class="control-label">@L["provincia"]</label>
                <CustomInputSelect @bind-Value="SelectedProvincia" id="Provincia" class="form-control">
                    @if (Provincias is null)
                    {
                        <option>Cargando...</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @foreach (var provincia in Provincias)
                        {
                            <option value="@provincia.IdProvincia">@provincia.Nombre</option>
                        }
                    }
                </CustomInputSelect>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <FormButtons PrimaryActionLabel=@L["crear"]
                         SecondaryActionLabel=@L["cancelar"]
                         ClickActionPrimary=@CrearLocalidad
                         ClickActionSecondary=@Cancel />
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {

    List<Provincia> Provincias;

    public Localidad Localidad = new Localidad();

    private void HandleSubmit()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Handling submit");
        CrearLocalidad();
    }

    public int SelectedProvincia { get; set; }

    protected async void CrearLocalidad()
    {
        var provincia = await _serviceProvincia.GetById(SelectedProvincia);

        //Localidad.IdProvincia = SelectedProvincia;
        Localidad.Provincia = provincia;

        await _serviceLocalidad.Insert(Localidad);

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Localidades");
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Provincias = await Task.Run(() => _serviceProvincia.GetAll());
        var PrimerProvincia = Provincias.FirstOrDefault();
        if (PrimerProvincia != null) {
            SelectedProvincia = PrimerProvincia.IdProvincia;
        }
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Localidades");
    }
}
```

**FormButtons.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
@inject IStringLocalizer<App> L;

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@ClickActionPrimary" value=@PrimaryActionLabel />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@ClickActionSecondary" value=@SecondaryActionLabel />
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string PrimaryActionLabel { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string SecondaryActionLabel { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback ClickActionPrimary { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback ClickActionSecondary { get; set; }

}
```

I've been reading about lifetime services, that's why I use *transient* in my dbcontext, it is creating a new instance per request.
For entities which don't have relationship with other models the CRUD is working properly, but with **Localidad Entity** which contains a **Provincia Entity** it is failing.
Also I think maybe the solution is related to **Entity State**,but I haven't dug deep enough. I'm trying to make some progress in my job atm.
Regarding entity state, I scaffolded some razor pages in other projects and the entity state is being tracked in the views, maybe I should go that way.

Any help to improve this code will be appreaciated, I'm a beginner with net core and backend in general *(I worked with frontend technologies only)*, and I'm still reading some books like *net core in action* and doing some courses but this exceeds my current knowledge.

Comment: The entire "generic repository" on top of EF Core  is an ugly antipattern and your `Update` can easily perform 43 DELETEs. You lost the transactional behavior of DbContext too, which means you now need to use an explicit database transaction. That's not the reason for the bug though (only indirectly). It doesn't matter if you used `Transient` because the scope in a Blazor server application is the user circuit (session). The `IService` and `IRepository` instances remain intact for the duration of a session and so use the same DbContext instance

Comment: [ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Entity Framework Core (EFCore)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0) explains how EF Core should be used in a Blazor Server app. Instead of `AddDbContext`, `AddDbContextFactory` is used to register a DbContextFactory. Components use that factory to create DbContext instances they dispose when they no longer need them.

Comment: thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I've been taking a look at some posts about the generic repository. I found this one https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126 so I already have a unit of work which is represented by the dbcontext and my repositories would be represented by the dbsets. So ef core is providing me with this functionality.  therefore can I have a interface for each model and implement the methods in the class of each model using dbsets directly? sorry to ask so many questions... but thanks a lot!

Comment: [Scope to the component lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0#scope-to-the-component-lifetime-1) explains how to scope a DbContext to the lifetime of a component so it behaves once again as a Unit-of-Work. 1) the component is created with ` DbFactory.CreateDbContext();` during initialization 2) the component implements IDisposable and disposes the DbContext. This way, unless you call `SaveChanges`, any modifications are discarded when you navigate away from a component

Comment: When entities become detached from their respective DbContext and then attached to other DbContext instances via methods like `Update` you are bound to run into all kinds of problems, especially when these entities have related entities. These related entities need to be checked against the DbContext tracked instances to replace references if present, and attach the references if not. (Otherwise potentially facing duplicate data or PK conflict exceptions) Adding Generics into the mix increases the headache as generics are unaware of class-specific details, so no visibility of references.

Comment: @MauroAlvarez I am having similar issues. Using repository pattern and injecting services on the page. Can you share how did you solve your issues?

Comment: It will help if you disable other controls calling DbContext execution during an execution is being processed.

Otherwise, mistakenly double-clicking will **start another execution before the first one finishes**.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the `DbContextFactory` from the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0) as per the comment by Panagiotis Kanavos is definitely needed regardless and will solve most cases of this error.

However the comment from Steve Py about entities becoming detached from their respective DbContext when trying to `Update` an entity with related entities is for more advanced cases. Two ways I found to solve it if this is the cause are:

1. null out the related entities before calling `Update`
2. set `EntityEntry.State` to `EntityState.Modified` instead of calling `Update`